# Disable LinkButton when OnClick Event Fires

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an asp:LinkButton as follows:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonNewServicesCategory" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;return false;" 
    style="float:left;margin-right:5px;" CausesValidation="False">new services category</asp:LinkButton>
```

The intent is that when the LinkButton is clicked, it disables itself and returns false to prevent the postback (this control is used as a trigger for an animation).

The behavior I'm experiencing is that the LinkButton correctly triggers the animation and returns false, but does not disable itself.

It's inside an updatepanel, but I'm sure that no postback is occurring.

Why doesn't this.disabled=true work?

Comment: Should probably just use an href anyway... but I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the way asp.net interacts with js but to disable an element with javascript use:

```
this.disabled=disabled; // not disabled=true
```

Then, to enable it again, remove the disabled attribute.

Comment: `this.disabled = true;` //to disable it, not `this.disabled = disabled;`  ... ; )

Comment: Danile, why don't you post your more elegant solution then?